# Get anchor tag HREF and VALUE

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing, find

I have a string that looks like this:

```
<a href="http://forum.tibia.com/forum/?action=board&boardid=476">Amera</a><br><font class="ff_info">This board is for general discussions related to the game world Amera.</font>
```

How can I ignore/remove everything after the `</a>` and then only get the url: `http://forum.tibia.com/forum/?action=board&boardid=476`and the value `Amera`

So afterwards, I want 2 variables with their values, like:

`string url = "http://forum.tibia.com/forum/?action=board&boardid=476";`

and

`string value = "Amera";`

I tried this to get the value:

```
string value = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(MYSTRING, "(<[a|A][^>]*>|)", "");
```

But it returns:

```
Amera</a><br><font class="ff_info">This board is for general discussions related to the game world Amera.</font>
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the URL, maybe try, this regex pattern: `/href=\"(.*)\"/`

...And to get the values between **`> Amera </a>`**
use a pattern like: `>(.+?)</a>`

...although, this seems far from perfect...

Answer (score 0):

If the `a` tag won't contain more attributes, you can use just this for the URL only:

```
\bhref="(.*?)"
```

And little more complex for URL and text:

```
<a\b[^>]*?\bhref="([^"]*?)"[^>]*?>(.*?)<\/a>
```

So in C# code (quotation marks need to be escaped!):

```cs
var html = "<a href=\"http://forum.tibia.com/forum/?action=board&boardid=476\">Amera</a><br><font class=\"ff_info\">This board is for general discussions related to the game world Amera.</font>";
var match = Regex.Match(html, "<a\\b[^>]*?\\bhref=\"([^\"]*?)\"[^>]*?>(.*?)<\\/a>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success) {
    var url = match.Groups[1];
    var text = match.Groups[2]
}
```

Comment: the url worked perfectly. but how can i get the text inside a-tags? (the value)

Comment: @rickastley Sorry, I forgot about the text - updated the post with a new regex which works for both url and text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HtmlDocument dc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        dc.LoadHtml("<a href='http://forum.tibia.com/forum/?action=board&boardid=476'>Amera</a><br><font class='ff_info'>This board is for general discussions related to the game world Amera.</font>");
        foreach (HtmlNode link in dc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("a"))
        {
            string url = link.Attributes["href"].Value; // http://forum.tibia.com/forum/?action=board&boardid=476
            string value = link.InnerText; // Amera
        }
```